# SQL OUTER JOIN returning some empty records - why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, outer-join

I have a table `project p` and a table `invoice i`, both of which have a project_id field. I want a result set that includes all the project_ids from `project` where `i.status = "Active"` and that also includes all the project_ids from `invoice` where `invoice_date > 2016-01-01` . Here's the query I've tried so far.

```
SELECT
    p.project_id
FROM
    (SELECT project_id
        FROM project 
        WHERE status = 'Active') p
FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT project_id
        FROM invoice 
        WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10),invoice_date, 20) > '2016-01-01') i
ON i.project_id = p.project_id
```

There are about 80 projects in `projects` with status=active and about 120 projects in `invoice` which have been invoiced since 2016-01-01. The above query returns about 140 records, which sounds right (some non-invoiced active projects, and some non-active invoiced projects). The problem is that the query has about half of the project_ids as empty (NULL?). It's as if it's not pulling in the project_ids from `invoice`. Please help me correct this.

Here is a short segment of the result set as an array...

```
...
[10] => Array
    (
        [project_id] => 
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [project_id] => C00F2097-CD36-4497-8B26-0BF59F90B1EA
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [project_id] => 217F3370-50F2-457E-A4F5-0C09F12E654A
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [project_id] => 
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [project_id] => B1A06823-73C8-4691-A3D6-0E1A234516B3
etc...
```

Comment: because those are the projects where that are `active`, but don't have a corresponding project from invoice where `invoice_date > '2016-01-01'`. And you might have cases where there are no `active` projects for the invoices

Comment: Include both tables project value in your select.   I'm also puzzled why you compare "dates" at a string value?  I suppose it will work since it's yyyy-mm-dd format; but seems safer to me to compare dates using a date datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to

```
SELECT coalesce(p.project_id, i.project_id) as project_id
```

and you won't have any null values.  The null values are the ones in invoice but not project.

Comment: Gordan's answer is better, but I'm going to leave this in the hope it helps you to understand what the problem was.

Answer (score 4):

Your description is just yelling "use `UNION`, use `UNION`"!

```
SELECT p.project_id
FROM project p
WHERE p.status = 'Active'
UNION  -- On purpose to remove duplicates
SELECT i.project_id
FROM invoice i
WHERE i.invoice_date > '2016-01-01';
```

Note:  There is no need to convert a date to a string to compare to a constant value.  In fact, that isn't a good idea (it prevents the use of indexes).

You can also phrase this using `UNION ALL`.  This is probably the cheapest way to get what you want (assuming that the tables have appropriate indexes):

```
SELECT p.project_id
FROM project p
WHERE p.status = 'Active'
UNION ALL
SELECT i.project_id
FROM invoice i
WHERE invoice_date > '2016-01-01' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM project p2
                  WHERE p2.project_id = i.project_id AND p.status = 'Active'
                 );
```

In this case, you might need `select distinct` in the `invoice` table if a project could have more than one index.

Comment: I heard you yelling that all the way over here.

Comment: I read that date literals should be 'YYYYMMDD' in SQL Server (no dashes), so that would have to be '20160101'.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . YYYYMMDD is technically the best form for date constants in SQL Server, because it is unambiguous regardless of internationalization settings.  I prefer YYYY-MM-DD because (1) it is (also) ISO 8601 compliant; (2) I am a human being (despite rumors to the contrary ;) and it is easier to read; (3) it is support by a wide variety of databases.